# Macbook unable to connect to RPi wifi using RaspAP

Tags: pi-3, networking

Maybe the wrong spot to post this, but I'm hoping to get some direction.

I'm trying to build a Wireless AP using RaspAP and a Pi 3B.  Everything seems to work fine, except for one little issue:  I can't get one machine(a Macbook Pro) to connect to the AP.  I've tried a Dell Laptop, iPhone, Nintendo Switch - all of these will connect.  Every time I try to connect the Mac, I get the following error: failed to send packet, permission denied.

```
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 available DHCP range: 10.3.141.50 -- 10.3.141.255  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 client provides name: Marks-MBP  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 10.3.141.255 a4:5e:60:d3:1d:b5  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 tags: wlan0  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 DHCPACK(wlan0) 10.3.141.255 a4:5e:60:d3:1d:b5 Marks-MBP  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 requested options: 1:netmask, 121:classless-static-route, 3:router,  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 requested options: 6:dns-server, 15:domain-name, 119:domain-search,  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 requested options: 252, 95, 44:netbios-ns, 46:netbios-nodetype  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 next server: 10.3.141.1  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 sent size:  1 option: 53 message-type  5  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 sent size:  4 option: 54 server-identifier  10.3.141.1  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 sent size:  4 option: 51 lease-time  12h  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 sent size:  4 option: 58 T1  6h  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 sent size:  4 option: 59 T2  10h30m  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 sent size:  4 option:  1 netmask  255.255.255.0  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 sent size:  4 option: 28 broadcast  10.3.141.255  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 sent size:  4 option:  3 router  10.3.141.1  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq-dhcp[966]: 2457421306 sent size:  4 option:  6 dns-server  10.3.141.1  
Sep  2 09:10:34 dnsmasq[966]: failed to send packet: Permission denied
```

Really just curious what permissions are being denied, from where, and how to correct.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks.   Definitely never used this platform.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help